# PHP : "Fatal error: Call to undefined function _determineIfPowerpc" when installing Pear

Tags: php, installation, pear

I'm working on an iMac with MacOS 10.9.5 and using PHP 5.4.45 (phpinfo details on demand).

To use ImageMagick, I understand I need to install PECL, and before that I need Pear. I've found [the relevant information](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php#installation.getting.osx) quite easily, thankfully, and have started applying it.

Of course, I've been doing the following with my admin account, which duly serves for such purposes.

The first step, `curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar`, works like a charm.

However, when I try `sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar` (recommended for a system-wide installation, which I feel I need to use PHP with my user account), I get the following message:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function _determineIfPowerpc() in phar:///Users/myadmin/Downloads/go-pear.phar/OS/Guess.php on line 159`

(Before launching the install, I do set my installation base to /usr/local/pear and my binaries directory to /usr/local/bin as recommended.)

I've noticed that the link to go-pear.phar on the above-linked page can be clicked simply and a big chunk of text and code appears; that code seems to have declarations for `_determineIfPowerpc()` that are consistent with its calls.

Am I doing something wrong, and if so, what is it?

Comment: This appears to be a [bug that was fixed recently](https://github.com/pear/pear-core/commit/b4b9fd83856888bb72591edc427ab9bad8030bd2#diff-46bbfed7904ff01e3563644982e10cc2c1a6748d7b8ecd9876920a9e728ba8f5). I don’t know the release cadence for Pear but you should follow that and possibly download some new code.

Answer (score 0):

As [Chris Haas already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733831/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-determineifpowerpc-when-install#comment121473669_68733831), you need to get `go-pear.phar` with at least version v1.10.13.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply need to run

```
apt install -y php-dev
```